# how to set default referral link

Tags: php

How can I set the condition of this code, I want to set the default referrer to incaenterprises when there is no one referred to my page.

```
<?php 

$ref = $_GET[ref]; 
if ($ref)
else
{
echo "incaenterprises";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ref = (isset($_GET['ref']) && !empty($_GET['ref']))
    ? $_GET['ref']
    : "incaenterprises"
;
```